# How to change the User Agent in mediaplayer of the android?

Tags: android, user-agent, android-mediaplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change android's default MediaPlayer User-Agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267502/how-to-change-androids-default-mediaplayer-user-agent)

How to change default **`User-Agent`** in **`MediaPlayer`** of the **`Android`**.. can we set a customized  User-Agent of the mediaplayer when you trying to get an Http streaming data....

Anyone know how do that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267502/how-to-change-androids-default-mediaplayer-user-agent